# How to add auto suggestion to the contact list in Android?

Tags: android, chat, applozic

I have been trying to add my own contact list which is coming from server to the auto suggestion search list in new message activity.

Comment: you've been trying? and?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a contact and then add it to the Applozic Contact Service.

```
Contact contact = new Contact();
contact.setUserId("adarshk");
contact.setFullName("Adarsh");
contact.setImageURL("R.drawable.applozic_ic_contact_picture_holo_light");
contact.setEmailId("contact@applozic.com");
```

AppContactService appContactService = new AppContactService(context);
appContactService.add(contact);

[Contact addition documentation](https://www.applozic.com/developers.html#android-sdk-contacts)